# I cant make rest calls with react

Tags: rest, reactjs, spring-boot

I am learning to use React at the moment, and I have a problem: I want react to work with my Java Spring Boot backend (Tomcat). React is running on port 3000 (default) and my Tomcat server on port 8080 (default). Now, when I make a REST call, I get the following error

```
script.js:13 GET http://localhost:8080/api/path?p=test net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

My rest call looks like:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/path?p=test')
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
```

What do I make wrong? I do not really have an idea.

Comment: Did you try sending request with postman or likely posting apps ? Other case, your backend is accepts cross origin requests ?

Comment: Try http://localhost:8080/api/path?p=test in your browser. Does it work?

Comment: Connection refused means exactly what it says, for some reason it cannot communicate with your backend. Check if your path is correct, if your backend is running, ... . We can't solve this issue with the info we have right now.

Comment: Okay, thank @g00glen00b .. im stupid, my backend was not running. Now my connection gets accepted, but I get `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: @ChristianPeters https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error is typically thrown when your frontend (React application) cannot connect to your backend (your Spring boot application). There are many possible reasons for this to happen, such as:

- Your back-end application is not running
- The path to your back-end application is not correct
- There is some kind of firewall between your front- and back-end application that is stopping the traffic
- ...

In your case it appeared to be the back-end application that was not running properly.

Your second problem is related to CORS, which is a mechanism that prevents JavaScript from connecting to other APIs/websites that are not on the same (sub)domain and port. In your case your frontend is running on a different port than you backend, so that means you have to deal with CORS.

To handle CORS, you have to add a header to your backend (namely the `Access-Contol-Allow-Origin` header the error is mentioning). With Spring, you can do that by adding the following annotation to your controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
```

Or you can configure CORS globally with a filter or using `WebMvcConfigurer`:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/api/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
        }
    };
}
```

As mentioned in the comments by @Lutz Horn, this is also described in a [Spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/).